# Schedule a task to be run everyday on my mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, setinterval

I've been trying to do something that sounds easy but can't manage to make it work.
I would like every day a function to be called so it will change a value in my database.
To do so I am using the setInterval() function from js

```
setInterval(()=>reset(),10000)
```

where my reset function is

```
function reset(){
  console.log("here")
  try{
      const user =  Users.updateMany(
          {$set : { voteAverage : 1 }}
      );
      console.log("good")
  }catch(err){
      res.json({message: err})
      console.log(err)
  }
}
```

I get back the good in my console but my database has not changed. I might do this the wrong way but I do not really know how to do that.
At first I tried to reset everything when I was patching a route and it worked. But now I do not want to use a route just want to make it run like this. Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems here

- `updateMany` is async operation but you are not awaiting it. So either await that and make your function async or return it as a promise.
- `updateMany` takes two parameter. First is filter and second is doc. I guess you are not providing any filter.

something like this

```
async function reset() {
  console.log("here");
  try {
    const user = await Users.updateMany(
      {"$set": {"voteAverage": 1}}
    );
    console.log("good");
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({"message": err});
    console.log(err);
  }
}

setInterval(async () => reset(), 10000);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, first of all I think I do not need to put any filter it will take all users and that's what I need. Secondly, you might be right for the async thing do you know what I can do to "counter" that?

Comment: I am not sure about that as if you want to update everything u might need to pass {} as first parameter. I have added the asyn/await based code in my answer. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hey, I might sound stupid but I think the error was just me that forgot to put my voteAverage between " "... but it worked nice thanks a lot